ending bracket in Latex error for multi line equation
I found the link eqnarray or align where it is suggested to not use eqnarray.
so I want to know how this equation will work in multiline with the last closing square bracket.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= & P_o\left[\left(D^2 \nabla \phi\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial m} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right) \\
& +4 R m\times(1-m)\left\{N-7.5-\frac{15}{27 Y} \frac{ \Delta U \left(J-J_L\right)}{L_i} \right\} C (1.0-45/8)+\kappa  \\
& +9.0\times  T_r + i7 + T_i \right]
\end{align*}

I get

I chose this overleaf format

this is a faq, use \bigl[ for the start and \bigr] for the end

You cannot use \left or \right across a line break (and trying to do so will produce an error). The amsmath package defines \Biggl and \Biggr and other similar groups of commands that can be used across line breaks.
